# Why can't I get all the objects in the path from firebase database in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The menu must be shown in full when moving in from one screen to another. It doesn't show all the menu in the list in that cases (just the latest element), on refresh it shows the full menu. And when I delete an element then also the whole menu collapses and only the latest element remains.enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uravu.png)

Please see the code below

```
componentDidMount() {
  /* Create reference to messages in Firebase Database */

  this.setState({ ...this.state, messages: [] });

  let messagesRef = fire
    .database()
    .ref("vendor/" + this.state.Day + "/" + this.state.Vendor + "/dishname")
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(100);
  messagesRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    /* Update React   state when message is added at Firebase Database */
    let message1 = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
    console.log(this.state.messages);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      messages: this.state.messages.concat(message1)
    });
  });
}

addMessage(e) {
  var newData = {
    Type: this.inputE3.value,
    Dish: this.inputEl.value,
    Price: this.inputE2.value
  };

  fire
    .database()
    .ref("vendor/" + this.state.Day + "/" + this.state.Vendor + "/dishname")
    .push(newData);

  this.inputEl.value = "";
  this.inputE2.value = "";
  this.inputE3.value = "";
  let messagesR = fire
    .database()
    .ref("vendor/" + this.state.Day + "/" + this.state.Vendor + "/dishname")
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(100);
  messagesR.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    /* Update React   state when message is added at Firebase Database */
    let message1 = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      messages: this.state.messages.concat(message1)
    });
  });
}

remove(id) {
  // console.log(this.state)
  let a = fire
    .database()
    .ref(
      "vendor/" + this.state.Day + "/" + this.state.Vendor + "/dishname/" + id
    );
  a.remove();
  this.setState({ ...this.state, messages: [] });
  //  this.componentDidMount();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.addMessage.bind(this)}>
        <input
          className="gocenter"
          id="one"
          type="text"
          ref={e3 => (this.inputE3 = e3)}
          placeholder="Veg or Non-Veg"
        />
        <input
          className="gocenter"
          id="one"
          type="text"
          ref={el => (this.inputEl = el)}
          placeholder="Enter the dish-name"
        />
        <input
          className="gocenter"
          id="one"
          type="text"
          ref={e2 => (this.inputE2 = e2)}
          placeholder="Enter the price"
        />
        <input className="submit" type="submit" value="Add Menu" />
        <br />
        <p id="oneline">
          {" "}
          <div id="one">Type </div>
          <div id="one"> Dish </div>
          <div id="one"> Price </div>
        </p>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {this.state.messages
          ? this.state.messages.map(message1 => (
              <li id="oneline" key={message1.id}>
                <div id="one">{message1.text.Type} </div>
                <div id="one"> {message1.text.Dish} </div>
                <div id="one"> {message1.text.Price}</div>{" "}
                <Button
                  className="submit"
                  onClick={this.remove.bind(this, message1.id)}
                >
                  Remove
                </Button>
              </li>
            ))
          : null}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `setState()` is an asynchronous task, so your code may not be working as expected due race conditions and your state being overwritten.

So you can encapsulate your logic in a function like so:

```
loadData() {
  const messagesRef = fire
    .database()
    .ref("vendor/" + this.state.Day + "/" + this.state.Vendor + "/dishname")
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(100);
  messagesRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    const message1 = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
    console.log(this.state.messages);
    this.setState({
      // ...this.state, <-- You can ommit this, as you are only interested in 
      //                     setting the messages property
      messages: this.state.messages.concat(message1)
    });
  });
}
```

and then call it in `componentDidMount` like this, using `setState` callback functionality:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ ...this.state}, () => this.loadData());
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. In console log after I navigate from another page it returns as an empty object:

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {text: {…}, id: "-LHK9aJ7wmeSt0spqbLi"}1: {text: {…}, id: "-LHM9najplQCSI92Utqc"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
Announcement.js:24 []
Vendor.js:181 []
Vendor.js:181 []
Vendor.js:181

Comment: Can you try setting the state in your delete method like this: `this.setState({ messages: messages.filter(msg => msg.id !== id) });`?

Answer (score 1):

You set `state.messages = []` in the remove function.

Comment: This means that when you call `remove`, all messages are cleared.

Comment: But when I navigate back I need to get all the elements already in the object instead I get only the latest on please see the console log:           (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {text: {…}, id: "-LHK9aJ7wmeSt0spqbLi"}1: {text: {…}, id: "-LHM9najplQCSI92Utqc"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0) Announcement.js:24 [] Vendor.js:181 [] Vendor.js:181 [] Vendor.js:181

Comment: Without a functional (minimal) example that showcases your problem it's nearly impossible to help you solve the problem. Please update your question with a complete minimal example that shows the problem. In this example, remove unneeded code.

Comment: Okay I will do so